# An issue with DllMain in COM in-proc DLL

Tags: c++, com, mingw

I have developed a C++ DLL-based in-proc COM server and successfully compiled it with MinGW + MSYS. If I compile it with `--enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,DLLMain.def` switches everything related to COM server works like a charm. However, this way some of the symbols got exported twice:

'dlltool -z output.def --export-all-symbols libCOMTest.dll' produces:

```
EXPORTS
    ...
    DeleteCriticalSection@4 @ 14
    DllCanUnloadNow @ 15 DATA
    DllCanUnloadNow@0 @ 16
    DllGetClassObject @ 17 DATA
    DllGetClassObject@12 @ 18
    DllMain @ 19 DATA
    DllMainCRTStartup@12 @ 20
    DllRegisterServer @ 21 DATA
    DllRegisterServer@0 @ 22
    DllUnregisterServer @ 23 DATA
    DllUnregisterServer@0 @ 24
    EnterCriticalSection@4 @ 25
    ...
```

And the linker generates a few warnings:

```
Warning: resolving _DllMain by linking to _DllMain@12
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups
Warning: resolving _DllGetClassObject by linking to _DllGetClassObject@12
Warning: resolving _DllCanUnloadNow by linking to _DllCanUnloadNow@0
Warning: resolving _DllRegisterServer by linking to _DllRegisterServer@0
Warning: resolving _DllUnregisterServer by linking to _DllUnregisterServer@0
```

If I omit these compiler options, the `DllMain` routine got unexported so I can't even register my COM server with `regsvr32` utility.

Below are some of the exported symbols of libCOMTest.dll :

```
EXPORTS
    ...
    DeleteCriticalSection@4 @ 14
    DllCanUnloadNow@0 @ 15
    DllGetClassObject@12 @ 16
    DllMainCRTStartup@12 @ 17
    DllRegisterServer@0 @ 18
    DllUnregisterServer@0 @ 19
    EnterCriticalSection@4 @ 20
    ...
```

As you can see there is no `DllMain` routine in the list.

My .def file looks as follows:

```
LIBRARY         libCOMTest
DESCRIPTION     'libCOMTest in-proc server'

EXPORTS
            DllMain         @1  PRIVATE
            DllGetClassObject   @2  PRIVATE
            DllCanUnloadNow     @3  PRIVATE
            DllRegisterServer   @4  PRIVATE
            DllUnregisterServer @5  PRIVATE
```

What is the reason the `DllMain` routine got unexported without `--enable-stdcall-fixup` compile switch? Are there any special tricks for building of in-proc COM server with MinGW + MSYS?

### The solution #1

As Hans suggested in his answer, it is possible to use the rename syntax in the .def file as follows:

```
EXPORTS
    DllGetClassObject   = DllGetClassObject@12
    DllCanUnloadNow     = DllCanUnloadNow@0
    DllRegisterServer   = DllRegisterServer@0
    DllUnregisterServer = DllUnregisterServer@0
```

The [guide to building and using Win32 DLLs in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/win32-dlls.html) suggests just the same.

### The solution #2

The other way is to make use of the `--kill-at` linker switch to strip out @nn part:

```
--kill-at
    If given, the stdcall suffixes (@nn) will be stripped from symbols 
    before they are exported.
```

Comment: You don't need to export anything but `DllGetClassObject`, `DllCanUnloadNow`, `DllRegisterServer` and `DllUnregisterServer` to get a working component; all of these need to be the *stdcall* variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know enough about your build tools but can extrapolate.  The linker is complaining because you asked to export "DllRegisterServer" but the compiler actually generated the identifier "DllRegisterServer@0" as required for the stdcall calling convention.  That's a mismatch.  The --enable-stdcall-fixup option is a workaround for that, putting the linker in 'fuzzy search mode' and allowing it to find a match.

Getting two exports is sloppy but not actually a problem, whatever code uses these entrypoints is always going to ask for the correct one.  Definitely try it without --export-all-symbols.  The only other thing you could try is to use the rename syntax in the .def file, not sure if your linker supports it:

```
        DllUnregisterServer=DllUnregisterServer@0  @5  PRIVATE
```